# NullException error in simple loging app

Tags: java, android

I am making a simple logging system in android. I am following this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/). While testing my app I am keep getting `NullException error`. This error is on this line `if(json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null)` in `LoginScreensActivity` below. I have no idea why is json is null. Please help me where am I making mistake.

Here is my code

function which triggers when login button is clicked. This is LoginScreensActivity.java class

```
btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
            String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
            UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
            JSONObject json = userFunction.loginUser(email,password);

            try {
                if(json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                    loginErrorMsg.setText("");
                    String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                    if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1) {
                        Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DashboardActivity.class);

                        // Close all views before launching Dashboard
                        dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(dashboard);

                        // Close Login Screen
                        finish();
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Login failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

loginUSer function which is triggered in above code

```
public JSONObject loginUser(String email, String password) {
    //Toast.makeText(context, "loginUser function", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", login_tag));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(loginUrl, params);
    //Log.e("JSON", json.toString());
    //Log.d("TAG", json.toString());
    return json;
}
```

here is my JSONPareser class

```
public class JSONParser {
static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

public JSONParser() {

}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {

    try {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;

        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "n");
        }

        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
        Log.e("JSON",json);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    return jObj;
}
}
```

here is my logcat

```
05-26 20:16:52.658: I/Process(31217): Sending signal. PID: 31217 SIG: 9
05-26 20:16:59.793: D/dalvikvm(31361): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 41K, 50% free 2725K/5379K, external 0K/0K, paused 31ms
05-26 20:16:59.843: D/dalvikvm(31361): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 7K, 50% free 2743K/5379K, external 455K/518K, paused 32ms
05-26 20:16:59.973: D/CLIPBOARD(31361): Hide Clipboard dialog at Starting input: finished by someone else... !
05-26 20:17:06.883: W/System.err(31361): java.net.UnknownHostException: zafarsaleem.info
05-26 20:17:06.883: W/System.err(31361):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:506)
05-26 20:17:06.883: W/System.err(31361):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:294)
05-26 20:17:06.883: W/System.err(31361):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:256)
05-26 20:17:06.883: W/System.err(31361):    at    org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:136)
05-26 20:17:06.883: W/System.err(31361):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
05-26 20:17:06.883: W/System.err(31361):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
05-26 20:17:06.883: W/System.err(31361):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:428)
05-26 20:17:06.883: W/System.err(31361):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
05-26 20:17:06.888: W/System.err(31361):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
05-26 20:17:06.888: W/System.err(31361):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
05-26 20:17:06.888: W/System.err(31361):    at library.JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONParser.java:38)
05-26 20:17:06.888: W/System.err(31361):    at library.UserFunctions.loginUser(UserFunctions.java:37)
05-26 20:17:06.888: W/System.err(31361):    at com.zafar.loginscreens.LoginScreensActivity$1.onClick(LoginScreensActivity.java:48)
05-26 20:17:06.888: W/System.err(31361):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2538)
05-26 20:17:06.888: W/System.err(31361):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9152)
05-26 20:17:06.888: W/System.err(31361):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-26 20:17:06.888: W/System.err(31361):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-26 20:17:06.888: W/System.err(31361):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-26 20:17:06.888: W/System.err(31361):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
05-26 20:17:06.888: W/System.err(31361):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-26 20:17:06.888: W/System.err(31361):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-26 20:17:06.888: W/System.err(31361):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
05-26 20:17:06.888: W/System.err(31361):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
05-26 20:17:06.888: W/System.err(31361):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-26 20:17:06.893: E/Buffer Error(31361): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
05-26 20:17:06.893: E/JSON Parser(31361): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
05-26 20:17:06.893: D/AndroidRuntime(31361): Shutting down VM
05-26 20:17:06.893: W/dalvikvm(31361): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001e578)
05-26 20:17:06.893: E/AndroidRuntime(31361): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-26 20:17:06.893: E/AndroidRuntime(31361): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-26 20:17:06.893: E/AndroidRuntime(31361):    at com.zafar.loginscreens.LoginScreensActivity$1.onClick(LoginScreensActivity.java:51)
05-26 20:17:06.893: E/AndroidRuntime(31361):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2538)
05-26 20:17:06.893: E/AndroidRuntime(31361):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9152)
05-26 20:17:06.893: E/AndroidRuntime(31361):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-26 20:17:06.893: E/AndroidRuntime(31361):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-26 20:17:06.893: E/AndroidRuntime(31361):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-26 20:17:06.893: E/AndroidRuntime(31361):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
05-26 20:17:06.893: E/AndroidRuntime(31361):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-26 20:17:06.893: E/AndroidRuntime(31361):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-26 20:17:06.893: E/AndroidRuntime(31361):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
05-26 20:17:06.893: E/AndroidRuntime(31361):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
05-26 20:17:06.893: E/AndroidRuntime(31361):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Update**

After adding `if(json != null && json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {` I get following logcat

```
05-26 20:44:46.243: W/System.err(32680): java.net.UnknownHostException: zafarsaleem.info
05-26 20:44:46.243: W/System.err(32680):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:506)
05-26 20:44:46.243: W/System.err(32680):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:294)
05-26 20:44:46.243: W/System.err(32680):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:256)
05-26 20:44:46.248: W/System.err(32680):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:136)
05-26 20:44:46.248: W/System.err(32680):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
05-26 20:44:46.248: W/System.err(32680):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
05-26 20:44:46.248: W/System.err(32680):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:428)
05-26 20:44:46.248: W/System.err(32680):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
05-26 20:44:46.248: W/System.err(32680):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
05-26 20:44:46.248: W/System.err(32680):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
05-26 20:44:46.248: W/System.err(32680):    at library.JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONParser.java:38)
05-26 20:44:46.248: W/System.err(32680):    at library.UserFunctions.loginUser(UserFunctions.java:37)
05-26 20:44:46.248: W/System.err(32680):    at com.zafar.loginscreens.LoginScreensActivity$1.onClick(LoginScreensActivity.java:49)
05-26 20:44:46.248: W/System.err(32680):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2538)
05-26 20:44:46.248: W/System.err(32680):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9152)
05-26 20:44:46.248: W/System.err(32680):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-26 20:44:46.248: W/System.err(32680):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-26 20:44:46.248: W/System.err(32680):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-26 20:44:46.248: W/System.err(32680):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
05-26 20:44:46.248: W/System.err(32680):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-26 20:44:46.248: W/System.err(32680):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-26 20:44:46.248: W/System.err(32680):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
05-26 20:44:46.248: W/System.err(32680):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
05-26 20:44:46.248: W/System.err(32680):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-26 20:44:46.248: E/Buffer Error(32680): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
05-26 20:44:46.248: E/JSON Parser(32680): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
```

Comment: Quite simply, it appears that `userFunction.loginUser(email,password);
` returns null.  You need to figure out why by analyzing that method.  What is loginUrl?

Comment: I tried to find it out but I couldnt find any problem with it. Could tell me how can I analyze it?

Comment: Try adding a debug statement to display the value of `json` before calling `new jSONObject(json)`.  You'r getting exceptions all over the place....  Try starting simple and getting small pieces of code to work step by step.  You're getting an exception when you try to connect to your url, which causes `is` to be null.  So... When you try to process `is` another exception is thrown.  First make sure you can connect to your url before you go any further.

Comment: You should debug thoroughly before posting 10GB code and error logs :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause of your trouble is a UnknownHostException, it seems the `email` EditText doesn't link to a valid URL which returns a null value for `json` causing the NullPointerException.

What are you entering in `email`?

**Addition**

To be explicit, the tutorial code:

```
if(json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
```

only checks if the String returned from getString() is not null. In your case `json` is null so you would need a test like this:

```
if(json != null && json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
```

to detect the null pointer and gracefully exit your app.

**Addition 2**

As the **User Functions Class** states, if your server is hosted online you need to change these lines of code in your `UserFunctions` class:

```
private static String loginURL = "http://10.0.2.2/ah_login_api/";
private static String registerURL = "http://10.0.2.2/ah_login_api/";
```

If you were Stack Overflow you could try something like:

```
private static String loginURL = "http://www.stackoverflow.com/ah_login_api/";
private static String registerURL = "http://www.stackoverflow.com/ah_login_api/";
```

But you are not Stack Overflow, of course, you need to point these URLs to your server and path.

Comment: Break your code into small pieces and get them to work step by step.  Don't be afraid to use a debugger or to add debug statements.  First make sure you can connect to your url before you go any further.

Comment: That is a long tutorial, it seems good but there are a lot of places it can go wrong. Here's my best guess: start in the "User Functions Class" section and make sure you are testing in the right environment (local or external).

Comment: Does my JSONParser class fine? I mean does it have any problem or it should work the way it is?

Comment: If you have copied the exact tutorial, I bet the classes are fine. The problem is simply the _URL_ that links to your server hosting the PHP code. You need to point it to the correct address. However I don't know how you have set up your server and am not very good at servers anyway...

Comment: Please see my update. I got different logcat after adding if statement which you mentioned. I am using an online server on my website.

Comment: Since you are using an online website you need to _change your URLs_ to that website, update my answer.

Comment: It is pointing to my website. So I think it should work and I also tested my server side code it also works.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the code is throwing an UnknownHostException which unequivocally means that URLs are not quite right...